# Solidworks C# can't extract item from feature that has TypeName equals "Reference"

Tags: c#, solidworks, solidworksapi

i have opened solidworks assembly (swDocumentTypes_e.swDocASSEMBLY) using C# and i have iterated through all the features in order to get all the Sketchs called 'ISO/XXX' under each part of the assembly, here is the code

```
public void openFile(string skeletonFilePath)
    {
        object[] Features = null;
        int i = 0;
        string FeatType = null;[1]
        string FeatTypeName = null;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(skeletonFilePath)) { return; }
        ModelDoc2 model = _sldWorks.OpenDoc("C:PATH/fileName.SLDASM", (int)swDocumentTypes_e.swDocASSEMBLY);
        Feature swFeat = default(Feature);
        SelectionMgr swSelMgr = default(SelectionMgr);
        swSelMgr = (SelectionMgr)model.SelectionManager;
        swFeat = (Feature)model.FirstFeature();

        while ((swFeat != null))
        {
            FeatType = swFeat.Name;
            FeatTypeName = swFeat.GetTypeName2();
            if ((FeatTypeName == "Reference")
            {
                Debug.Print(" Name of feature: " + swFeat.Name);
                    Debug.Print(" Type of feature: " + swFeat.GetTypeName2());


            }
            swFeat = (Feature)swFeat.GetNextFeature();

        }

    }
```

**the problem**:
each time i try to  extract the items under the feature (of one part) i got an exception, i have to tried these ways:

- swFeat.GetDefinition() // i've  got null exception
- swFeat.GetSpecificFeature2() // i've got dynamic value which i don't know the class i need to cast with
- var childs = (Object[])swFeatSupport.GetChildren(); // i've got only to constraints under the part

[example of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgFYS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only iterating over top level features. You can use IFeature::GetFirstSubFeature() and IFeature::GetNextSubFeature to get sub feature. Make this function recursive so it will iterate over all features, regardless of how many levels deep they are. Another layer you need to consider is the components - you need to iterate over components in an assembly first if you need feature data in the context of individual parts.

[Here's](https://help.solidworks.com/2021/english/api/sldworksapi/Traverse_Assembly_at_Component_and_Feature_Levels_Using_Recursion_Example_CSharp.htm) an example from the Solidworks API documentation. Its poorly written (IMO) but it will guide you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, it is really helpful, but the new problem i'm having right now is that the sketch values are based on  that part coordinate system not the assembly one, in other words, if my sketch contains a fixed point, the X Y and Z values of that point are measured by the part coordinate system(just like when we open that part only), but i want the position of that  point in the assembly.

Comment: You need to transform the coordinates to assembly space. That topic is a little too lengthy to explain here but [this article](https://cadbooster.com/complete-overview-of-matrix-transformations-in-the-solidworks-api/) goes over most of it. 

If you decide to outsource this, I recommend [S3L Solutions](https://s3lsolutions.com/). Full disclosure - I am affiliated with that company.